# Is the map $\Psi:S \to \ell^2$ a bijection?

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $S$ be the set of all entire functions $f$ such that $|f(z)| \le Ae^{\pi |z|}$ for all complex $z$ and $f \in L^2(-\infty,\infty)$. Let $\ell^2$ be the set of of all complex sequences $\{x_n\}$ such that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty |x_n|^2<\infty$. Take $\Psi:S \to \ell^2$ to be the map $\Psi(f)=\{f(1),f(2),\ldots\}$. Show that $\Psi$ is a bijection. My work is that if $\Psi(f-g)=0$, then I want to show that $f=g$. I can show that $f(n)=g(n)$ for $n=1,2,\ldots$. Combining this and the paley-wiener, we can show that
\begin{equation}
\int_{-\pi}^\pi [F(\theta)-G(\theta)]e^{in\theta}d\theta=0
\end{equation} for some $F,G \in L^2(-\infty,\infty)$, where $n=1,2,\ldots$. Then I stop here. Are my approach of proving injection of $\Psi$ correct?

Comment: Surjectivity is more evident to me, by considering $f(z)=\sum_{n\geq 1}f(n)\,\text{sinc}(\pi(z-n))$

Comment: If you're learning this Paley-Weiner stuff I would have thought you must already know _Parseval_...

Comment: @David C. Ullrich, Oh, yes. I know that.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio, Why are you sure that your infinite sum of sinc functions is entire?

Comment: I can only prove that the function $f(z)=\sum_{n \ge 1} f(n)sinc (\pi(z-n))$ is entire if $|f(n)| \le C/n^2$ for some constant $C$.

Comment: In fact $\sum|f(n)|^2<\infty$ is enough, by orthogonality in a certain Hilbert space...

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich, Yes, I have tried to think of using the fact that $\ell^2$ is Hilbert, but I failed. Could you please give me more hints? Thanks....

Comment: In fact $\Psi f=0$ if $f(z)=\text{sinc}(\pi(z+1))$, so $\Psi$ is not injective. You should have defined $\Psi:S\to\ell_2(\Bbb Z)$ instead of $\ell_2(\Bbb N)$.

Comment: don't know if you noticed, but I posted a complete answer instead of more hints...

Comment: Yes, I got it. I am studying it. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

If you know the Paley-Wiener theorem this result should just fall out by Parseval. I re-read the question. In fact the version above is *wrong*; it's the correct version that's trivial...$\newcommand\s{\operatorname{sinc}}$ (if $f(z)=\s(\pi(z+1))$ then $\Psi f=0$).

So we change the definition of $\Psi f$ to be the bilateral sequence $$\Psi f=(f(n))_{n\in\Bbb Z}.$$

(Note that at this point it would be wrong to write $\Psi:S\to\ell_2$ as you did; we will see below that in fact $\Psi:S\to\ell_2$, but that's not clear yet.)

For $F\in L^2([-\pi,\pi])$ define $f=\hat F\in H(\Bbb C)$ by $$f(z)=\hat F(z)=\int_{-\pi}^\pi F(t)e^{-izt}\,dt.$$For $n\in\Bbb Z$ define $e_n\in L^2(-\pi,\pi)$ by $$e_n(t)=e^{int},$$so $(e_n)_{n\in\Bbb Z}$ is an orthonormal basis for $L^2(-\pi,\pi)$. Let $$s_n(z)=\hat e_n(z)=\s(\pi(z-n)).$$

Now if we define a norm in $S$ by $$||f||_S=||\hat F||_{S}=||F||_{L^2}$$then $S$ becomes a Hilbert space, with $(s_n)_{n\in\Bbb Z}$ as an orthonormal basis. So for every $f\in S$ there exists a unique sequence $\alpha\in\ell_2(\Bbb Z)$ with $$f=\sum_{\alpha\in\Bbb Z}\alpha_ns_n,$$**with** convergence in $S$.

> > **Easy Lemma:** If $K\subset\Bbb C$ is compact there exists $c$ such that $|\hat F(z)|\le c||F||_{L^2}$ for every $z\in K$ and $F\in L^2$.

So the series $f=\sum \alpha_ns_n$ converges uniformly on compact sets, hence to an entire function. And hence it converges pointwise, so $\alpha_n=f(n)$.

**Hence** $\langle f, s_n\rangle = f(n)$, so the fact that $(s_n)$ is an orthonormal basis says precisely that $\Psi$ is a bijection from $S$ onto $\ell_2(\Bbb Z)$.